# Why do we use array_name.dtype versus dtype(array_name) in python, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, to check the type of array the code is

```
type(array_name)
```

but to check the type of the values stored in the array the code is

```
array_name.dtype
```

I would have thought it would be

```
dtype(array_name)
```

This problem keeps arises in different contexts as well.

Comment: I assume you mean type(array_name) and not test(array_name) ?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Why is it a problem? That's just the way numpy was written. `dtype` is an attribute of an instance of the class `numpy.ndarray`. `numpy.dtype` is also its own class, not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, **type** is a **built-in function** that returns the type of anything you pass to it in argument. You could call `type(x)` without any assumption on x and Python would tell you about the type of x.

On the other hand, numpy arrays are objects. As such they have a certain number of **attributes** and one of them is **dtype**. Only numpy arrays (and other objects that follow the same logic) have dtypes: it wouldn't make sense to ask for the dtype of an integer for example.

Answer (score 2):

[`dtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html#numpy.ndarray.dtype) is the type of *the contents of the array*, and it's a numpy (and pandas)-specific thing. It's easier and more convenient both for the developers and the users of the library to store it as such.

[`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) returns the Python type of *any object*, is a Python built-in function. While the designers of Python could have made it a property on every object, they chose to make it a global function.

`dtype` and `type` seem very similar in this case, but in reality, they have nothing to do with each other.